# series of SSL errors across multiple sites -- reason for concern?

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle

Rebooted my rMBP late 2013 recently, and saw a set of SSL errors (unable to verify certificate) across a wide range of sites (google, gmail, mubi, medium) and also in the Calendar app as it tried to connect to Google. Never seen this kind of thing before -- any reason for concern?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific system misconfiguration which is not likely to be of benefit to others

Answer (score 1):

never mind, found the answer: my computer's time was incorrectly set on reboot for some reason.